# Translating multiple characters into one

Tags: java, character, translate

I need help converting Morse Code to English. I have already written and tested the code for translating English to Morse. My main problem is having all the characters in the Morse code together before translating it to an English character if that makes sense.

Example: "." translates to E and ... translates to S, but I don't want the translation to start until it reaches ...

Few Rules
-Spaces are used to separate Morse Letters
-| is used as an delimiter to separate words
-Cant use an hashmap :(

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class test3
{
public static void main ( String [] args )
{

    String s1 = "Morse";

    // Decide whether Morse code or English
    String decide = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 'English' for Morse to English code translation and 'Morse' for English to Morse code translation. Pay attention to Caps.");

    // Enter String & decide whether to convert to Morse or English
    String phrase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the words you wish to translate.");

    if ( decide.equals( s1 ))
        toMorse( phrase );

    else
        toEnglish( phrase );
}

// Translate to Morse
public static void toMorse( String preTranslation )
{

    String[] english = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"};

    String[] morse = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..", ".---",
            "-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-", 
            "...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..",".----","..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----.","-----"};
    // Remove uppercase
    String preTrans = preTranslation.toLowerCase();

    // Deletes spaces
    String phraseWithDelimiter = preTrans.replace( " ", "|");

    String[] translation = new String[phraseWithDelimiter.length()];
    String[] delimiter = {"|"};

    // Translate 
    for ( int arrayVar = 0, transArrayVar = 0, subStringVarB = 0, subStringVarE = 1; transArrayVar < phraseWithDelimiter.length();)
    {
        if( phraseWithDelimiter.substring(subStringVarB, subStringVarE).equals( delimiter[0] ) )
        {
            translation[transArrayVar] = delimiter[0];
            transArrayVar++;
            subStringVarB++;
            subStringVarE++;
        }
        else if ( phraseWithDelimiter.substring(subStringVarB, subStringVarE).equals( english[arrayVar] ) )
            {
                translation[transArrayVar] = morse[arrayVar];
                transArrayVar++;
                subStringVarB++;
                subStringVarE++;
                arrayVar = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                arrayVar++;
                if ( arrayVar == 35 )
                {
                    arrayVar = 0;
                    subStringVarB++;
                    subStringVarE++;
                    transArrayVar++;
                }
            }
    }
String morseSeparator = new String( " " );
arrayToString ( translation, morseSeparator );

}


//Convert array to string and print translation
public static void arrayToString(String[] trans, String separator) 
{
    String result = "";
    if (trans.length > 0) 
    {
            result = trans[0];    // start with the first element
            for (int i = 1; i < trans.length; i++)
                result = result + separator + trans[i];
        }
    System.out.println( result );
}

    // unfinished
public static void toEnglish( String preTranslation)
{
    }
```

I was thinking about making a for statement and assigning every character of the Morse code to a new string until I reach a white space and then using that to test but I'm unsure about how to do that.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to use a `HashMap`? I'd say use a `TreeMap` then, but I guess you're not allowed to use that either, are you? This requirement feels like homework, if this is the case, please add the corresponding tag.

Comment: You should split up your Morse input around pipes and spaces before processing using [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)). You'll get a list of words, each of which is a list of complete morse letters; you can compare those to your alphabet easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a regular expression containing all the Morse code sequences in order from longest to shortest.

```
 Pattern.compile("----\\.|-----|---\\.\\.|...")
```

and then just match that repeatedly against a string to get the longest valid Morse code sequence.

---

Alternatively, you can use a parser compiler like [JavaCC](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-Tutorial/javacc-tutorial.pdf).

```
SKIP : { " " }
TOKEN : { < A : "-." > }
TOKEN : { < B : "-..." > }
TOKEN : { < C : "-.-." > }
...

String translate() :
{ StringBuilder sb; }
{
  { sb = new StringBuilder(); }

  (
    letter(sb)
  )*
  <EOF>

  { return sb.toString(); }
}

void letter(StringBuilder sb) :
{}
{
  ( <A>
    { sb.append('a'); }
  | <B>
    { sb.append('b'); }
  | <C>
    { sb.append('c'); }
  ...
  )
}
```

Comment: To make building that pattern easier, you might want to loop over the `morse` array (which should be sorted correctly) and build the pattern dynamically.

Comment: @Thomas, Yeah.  If you can use [Google commons](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html), you can do something like `"\\Q" + Joiner.on("\\E|\\Q").join(morse) + "\\E"`.

Comment: so how do I use pattern.compile? Is there a method to test only a certain portion of that method even if the length is different each time?

Comment: @Albert, `Pattern x = Pattern.compile(...)` will give you a pattern instance in `x`.  You can then do `x.matcher(myString)` to get a matcher and the [`Matcher` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) explains how to use the `find`, `group`, `start`, and `end` methods to iteratively break the string into maximal chunks.

Answer (score 1):

For translating the text you might try and split it on word delimiters first, then on character limiters. Then process the words one by one. Similar to this:

```
String morseInput = //whatever, only delimiters or morse characters

String[] words = morseInput.split("-|");
for( String word : words ) {
  String[] characters = word.split("\\s");

  for( String c : characters ) {
    //look up the english character for c - I'd use a map here
  }
}
```

A few notes:

- I omitted checks for empty strings and null for brevity
- I also left out any code to build the final translation string, that's an excercise for you
- I'd use a `Map<String, String>` for the lookup, if that's not allowed, look up the index of the character in the source array and then get the translation at that index from the translation array

Comment: If you're splitting on literals, you should probably use `Pattern.quote()`, easier to make sure everything is escaped right.